# Un-committed database transactions and auto-increment columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, transactions, auto-increment

I encountered some curious behavior today and was wondering if it is expected or standard.  We are using Hibernate against MySQL5.  During the course of coding I forgot to close a transaction, I presume others can relate.

When I finally closed the transaction, ran the code and checked the table, I noticed the following.  All the times I mistakenly ran my code without closing the transaction, which therefore did not result in actual rows being inserted, nevertheless incremented the auto-increment surrogate primary key value, so that I have a gap (i.e. no rows with id field value of 751 to 762).

Is this expected or standard behavior?  Might it vary depending on the database?  And/or does Hibernate's own transaction abstraction have some possible effect on this?

Comment: I knew the answer, but this is still an interesting question!

Comment: Ideally your application/design shouldn't be affected by any gaps in the sequence - you should never get yourself in a situation where this actually matters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes that's expected.

If you think about it: what else can the database do? If you increment the column and then use that as a foreign key in other inserts within the same transaction and while you're doing that someone else commits then they can't use your value. You'll get a gap.

Sequences in databases like Oracle work much the same way. Once a particular value is requested, whether or not it's then committed doesn't matter. It'll never be reused. And sequences are loosely not absolutely ordered too.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty much expected behaviour. With out it the db would have to wait for each transaction that has inserted a record to complete before assigning a new id to the next insert.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is expected behaviour.  [This documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) explains it very well.

Beginning with 5.1.22, there are actually three different lock modes that control how concurrent transactions get auto-increment values.  But all three will cause gaps for rolled-back transactions (auto-increment values used by the rolled-back transaction will be thrown away).

Answer (score 0):

Database sequences are not to guarantee id sequence without gaps. They are designed to be transaction-independent, only in such way can be non-blocking.

You want no gaps, you must write your own stored procedure to increase column transactionally, but such code will block other transactions, so you must be carrefull.

You do SELECT CURRVAL FROM SEQUENCE_TABLE WHERE TYPE = :YOUR_SEQ_NAME FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE SEQUENCE_TABLE SET CURRVAL = :INCREMENTED_CURRVAL WHERE TYPE = :YOUR_SEQ.